# Using NSFetchedResultsController to get a random object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I would like to fetch a random object from a fetch request that I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` with.  This is what I had:

```
int randIndex = arc4random() % [[_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
randomObject = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:randIndex];
```

However, I don't think I'm doing this correctly, as it is causing crashes.  Could someone please provide me some advice?

Comment: What kind of crash?  what is the value of randIndex?  what is the value of count?

Comment: I'm just trying to use count to get the number of objects from the NSFetchedResultsController.  I take that number, use arc4random() on it, and get a random key which I then use to select a random object from the controller.  Of course, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int randIndex = arc4random() % [[_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
randomObject = [[_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:randIndex];
```

The crash is because NSFetchedResultsController doesn't respond to -objectAtIndex:.

Comment: nice catch. I looked at this question earlier and I didn't spot the mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the find!  I also realized what was causing the odd crash without warning- I had NSLog test lines that were trying to print randIndex with %@ when I should have been using %i.